# move to the next record using next button in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display database records in details view. I need to move from one record to another using next button

I have a text box that display the record id. this code is working, but it stop in before the last record and not showing the last one.

this is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataReader dr;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from quoation111 where id=1";
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "1";
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    string s = "select count(*) from quoation111";
    cmd.CommandText = s;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (s != TextBox1.Text)
    {
        int s1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + 1;
        TextBox1.Text = s1.ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx");
    }

}
```

Comment: You are comparing s to textbox. S = "select count(*) from quoation111" and not the count of table rows. It will always take textbox value and will add 1 to it. It will be infinite. It will never go to else part. Did you provide actual code?

Comment: Could you mention how many number of rows are there in the quotation table ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri yes i try this but still the same problem

Comment: @BhanuChandra there are 10 rows

Comment: Yes, It will be an infinite loop..could you provide the full code !!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method to read the value,do some changes relatively !!!

```
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
string s = "select count(*) from quoation111";
cmd.CommandText = s;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds); //Filling Data into Data Adapter  

int rowcount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count ;

for (int i = TextBox1.Text;i<= rowcount;i++)
{
   TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```